# run btrfs balance with cron

Tags: filesystems, cron, btrfs

Since I run today in a problem with a full disk, which turns out is not unbalanced. Which you can fix with `btrfs balance`.

So my question is:

Is there any risk by ruining this by a cron job? (in cases where my laptop go to sleep)

Comment: Balance is for when you add a new disk to the fs; it is not something you do on a regular basis.

Comment: @psusi that was what I thought first, but btrfs balance also free up unused blocks. A detailed description is here http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2014-05-04_Fixing-Btrfs-Filesystem-Full-Problems.html

Comment: That article is misleading.  While it is true that `btrfs df` reports only chunk usage, which can be higher than actual usage if chunks are only partly used, `df` reports a proper amount of free space.  Partially filled chunks don't matter so there is no reason to bother with a balance simply to make the output of `btrfs df` look nicer.  In other words, free blocks are free blocks, whether they are part of a chunk or not; either way they are available for use by files on demand.

Comment: Well but if you have Mis-balanced data chunks and the disk is 100% full programs start to crash because they can't write

Answer (score 1):

Sir I33tname gave you the answer.

However you should be running separate cron job that checks for nearly full disks.
This is an idea how to do that, NOT necessarily a perfect solution for your situation

Use cronjob -e to add this (example change names of directories and files):
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh 2>>/path/to/logfile

script.sh has something like this (check the output of df  -h -- I am assuming col #5 is the %full, and this assumes 90%  is the start of problems and you have email setup):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 df -h  | awk 'INT($5)>80 { print }{next}' > /path/to/diskfull.txt
 [  -s /path/to/diskfull.txt ] && /usr/bin/mailx -s 'disk full error ' [your email name here ] < /path/to/diskfull.txt
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution if I can't automate the balance, I consider it and mark it eventually as answer if nobody find a better solution.

Comment: In my case this wouldn't work because btrfs said the disk is full. Almost any task ended up in `no space left on device`, but when I checked `df -h` it told me `/dev/mapper/cryptroot   93G   59G   35G  64% /`. But there was another command that showed me the full filesystem: `btrfs fi show`: `devid    1 size 92.68GiB used 92.68GiB path /dev/mapper/cryptroot`.